# Metric compatibility and torsion-free condition of GR

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor

In an introduction to general relativity, we see that the unique connection of a manifold is described by both these conditions : metric compatibility and torsion-free condition. The metric free condition can be physically understood as allowing us to parallel transport vectors between two tangent spaces. But what is the importance of the torsion free condition? The problem would be no unique connection for a manifold. Is it an issue in GR ? I mean is there any way which can relax this condition ?

Comment: The torsion-free connection can be thought of as a postulate which is part of the definition of standard GR. Nevertheless, it is not something really necessary. There exists, for example, the Einstein-Cartan theory of gravity (https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0606062), which is an extension of standard GR in which the torsion-free connection requirement is dropped. This is relevant, e.g., for supergravity theories.

Comment: You are then worried that the manifold would have no unique connection. Well, the Einstein equations determine the metric of the manifold in terms of the stress tensor of matter sources. The metric then still determines by metric compatibility the symmetric part of the connection coefficients. If you further impose the torsion-free condition, you are done and the connection is fully specified. If you do not impose the torsion-free condition, you introduce an additional equation relating the torsion tensor to the spin of the matter sources.

Comment: As such, together with the Einstein equations the connection on the tangent bundle is still determined by the matter distribution.

Answer (score -1):

For knowing why the Torsion tensor is important it is important to know what it is.So,
$$[\nabla_\mu ,\nabla_\nu]f=T^\lambda_{\mu \nu}\nabla_\lambda f$$
Where T is the torsion tensor, so if your covariant derivatives commute you have  torsion free manifold. Quickly working out the commutator of the covariant derivatives will shows you that
$$T^\lambda_{\mu \nu}=\Gamma^\lambda_{\mu \nu}-\Gamma^\lambda_{\nu \mu}$$
So when we talk about your metric compatibility we are assuming that the metric is diagonal. In that case your Riemann Christoffel Tensor is also symmetric under exchange of μ and ν which leads to a torsion free manifold. You bring out a metric that has a non diagonal and non zero component and suddenly both conditions vanish such as in the case of the Einstein Cartan Theory which is mentioned by`@gold`

Comment: "So when we talk about metric compatibility we are assuming that the metric is diagonal". I don't understand what this is supposed to mean. The metric being diagonal or not just depends on the basis you choose to write down its components and therefore it has nothing to do with the connection. For example, in Minkowski space with Cartesian coordinates $(x^0,x^1,x^2,x^3)$ the metric is diagonal $$ds^2=-(dx^0)^2+d\vec{x}\cdot d\vec{x}.$$ If you switch to retarded coordinates $(u,r,z,\bar z)$ for example, the metric is not diagonal $$ds^2=-du^2-2dudr+2r^2\gamma_{z\bar z}dzd\bar z.$$

Comment: Nevertheless, it is the *same metric* just written in different bases.

Comment: Work out the Christoffel symbols and see if they are symmetric or not. Because coordinate transformations change the metric and the connection a you may know. You'll see my point.

Comment: Let $x^\mu$ and $\bar x^\mu$ be two coordinate systems. The transformation law of the connection coefficients is well-known to be $$\bar \Gamma^\sigma_{\phantom\sigma\mu\nu} = \dfrac{\partial \bar x^\sigma}{\partial x^\gamma}\dfrac{\partial x^\alpha}{\partial \bar x^\mu}\dfrac{\partial x^\beta}{\partial \bar x^\nu}\Gamma^\gamma_{\phantom\gamma\alpha\beta}+\dfrac{\partial^2 x^\gamma}{\partial \bar x^\mu \partial \bar x^\nu}\dfrac{\partial \bar x^\sigma}{\partial x^\gamma}.$$

Comment: Assuming $\Gamma^\gamma_{\phantom\gamma\alpha\beta}$ symmetric, i.e., the connection coefficients are symmetric in the system $x^\mu$, it immediately follows that $\bar \Gamma^\sigma_{\phantom\sigma\mu\nu}$ is also symmetric. Indeed the first term is the usual coordinate transformation of a tensor, which clearly maps symmetric objects into symmetric objects. The second term is manifestly symmetric under $\mu\leftrightarrow\nu$. In conclusion, transformation of coordinates *never* create one anti-symmetric part on the connection coefficients if they were originally symmetric.

Comment: You don't understand. Using a well known result is a bad idea as many results are born out of assumptions. In this case you are right about the transformation law, the second term is invariant under swapping of coordinates but the first one is not.

Comment: I think you are getting confused about my point. Because  even in retarded coordinates you get a symmetric metric which can be transformed into a diagonal one quite easily by doing a backwards transformation. If you were to use something like the Kerr metric you would get that Torsion tensor would not be 0.This all boils down to what the Christoffel Connection.$$\Gamma^\lambda _{\mu \nu}=\frac1 2 g^{\lambda \sigma }[\partial _\mu g_{\nu \sigma }+\partial _\nu g_{\sigma \mu }-\partial_\sigma g_{\mu \nu}]$$

Comment: Swapping the $\mu$ and $\nu$ will give you $$\Gamma^\lambda _{\nu \mu}=\frac 1 2 g^{\lambda \sigma}[\partial _\nu g_{\mu \sigma}+\partial_\mu g_{\sigma \nu}-\partial_\sigma g_{\nu \mu} ]$$. Now using the fact (as i have already shown) that the torsion tensor is just the difference of the Riemann Christoffel Symbols, you can know subtract both of them to come to a direct equation for the torsion tensor which is

Comment: $$T^\lambda _{\mu \nu}=\Gamma^\lambda_{\mu \nu}-\Gamma^\lambda_{\nu \mu}$$ $$=\frac1 2 g^{\lambda \sigma}[\partial _\mu (g_{[{\nu \sigma}]}+\partial _\nu g_{[{\sigma \mu}]}-\partial_\sigma g_{[{\nu \mu}]}]$$ You see that if the metric remains the same afteer the swap the torsion tensor is zero. So if require some torsion you need  $g_{[{\mu \nu}]}=g_{\mu \nu}-g_{\nu \mu}$ to not be zero.

Comment: As @Gold stated, diagonalization of metric components only depends on choice of basis $g_{ij}=e_ie_j$ and not on choice of connection. $g_{ab}$ is a symmetric bi-linear map... so it doesn't make sense to talk about $g_{[ab]}$ being non-zero

Comment: I don't understand why you are still stuck on the diagonalization of metric. I think you should be aware that any symmetric tensor can be transformed into a diagonal one. But that doesn't make any difference at all it is irrelevant to the point. The Torsion tensor is the antisymmetric part of the Christoffel tensors and directly depends upon the antisymmetry of the metric tensor. Thats it, no need to talk about anything.

Comment: I'm sorry, but you are confusing several things. As @KP99 mentions, the metric tensor is a bi-linear symmetric map **by definition**. This is true in standard GR, in Einstein-Cartan theory or any other variant you might think of. This means $g_{[\mu\nu]}=0$ *by definition*. You seem to think that when torsion is nonzero, we still have the same formula for the Christoffel symbols, just with a metric that has an anti-symmetric part. This is just wrong and is just standard Differential Geometry. That formula is true just for the symmetric part. The metric *never* acquires an anti-symmetric part.

Comment: As you are unable to comprehend what i'm saying . Go to this link-https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Torsion_tensor . See what the components are. The metric is not alway s symmetric. It is a billinear mapping but you can't assume as a axiom that there is no antisymmetry. Go see the antisymmetric part of the kerr metric.

Comment: What do you mean? There is no anti-symmetric part of Kerr metric.

Comment: The Kerr metric is a symmetric bi-linear form as any other metric.